# error <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="3" android:minSdkVersion="11"></uses-sdk>

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, permissions

I was using Eclipse when it said that my version 10 SDK needs to be upgraded to above 17, so I upgraded to the latest vestion on SDK tools version 19.
Now when I go to AndroidManifest.xml it throws errors on these 2 lines below.

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="3" android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

THE COMPLETE AndroidManifest.xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.golf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="3" android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Can you help? what am I doing wrong? It was working perfectly on v10.

Comment: target is below min that doesn't seem logical, how can your target something unsupported?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you have mentioned

> uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion android:minSdkVersion

**two times** in manifest.xml.One before application tag and one after

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.golf"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="3" android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>  <-- Remove this
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Many thanks, that error disappeared, but i still have the error, or a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark, on the line, 
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="3" android:minSdkVersion="4"></uses-sdk>

Comment: thats because your targetsdk version is less than minsdk version.and yello triangle is just a warning

Comment: thanks alot you have been of major help, but i noticed in the "console" box it said "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\\platform-tools\lib" ,  so it has 2 back slashes \\platform-tools\lib, this was caused by incomplete installation on my part, so it cannot find the "dx.jar" so when i go to export and compile the project app i now get this error that unable to build: the file dx.jar was not loaded from the SDK folder!

Comment: Anyways the problem you mentioned about manifest error is solved.so i would suggest you to put that i another question